# Best practice to use the same function with different structs - Golang

Tags: string, function, go, struct, overloading

So let's say that I have different structs, which have common fields, and I want to use the same toString method for both.
Because the logic and the flow will be exactly the same. And I don't want to duplicate it. I'm thinking about what can be done about this.

```
type mobile struct {
   "version" string,
   "appName" string
}


type other struct {
   "release" string,
   "app_name" string
}
```

So let's say I have these two structs. Actually, the version holds the same meaning as the release. And mobile > appName and other> app_name  again holds the same meaning.

So I want to write one `toString` method where I can list the details of these two objects.

```
func detailsOfMobile(app mobile) string {
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Here is the details of the *%s* with the version %s", app.appName, app.version)
    .....
    return message
```

}

so for other I need to duplicate it;

```
    func detailsOfOther (app Ipad) string {
        message := fmt.Sprintf("Here is the details of the *%s* with the version %s", app.app_name, app.release)
        .....
        return message
   }
```

Actually the methods are much more complicated in reality. But what I'm trying to stay here, both structs have common fields, but they are named differently. What can be the best practice here not to duplicate the code?

Comment: "both structs have common fields, but they are named differently" the only thing they have in common is their type, `string`.

Comment: Best practice is to duplicate code.

Comment: Though it is slightly different than your question, I stumbled onto something similar and solved it like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251278/golang-best-practice-for-using-same-function-for-two-structs-with-same-field/74251279#74251279

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices, the closest way of doing what you are literally asking is to use an interface. Your function accepts a common interface and your structs both implement it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type App interface {
    Name() string
    Version() string
}

type mobile struct {
    version string
    appName string
}

func (m mobile) Name() string    { return m.appName }
func (m mobile) Version() string { return m.version }

type other struct {
    release  string
    app_name string
}

func (o other) Name() string    { return o.app_name }
func (o other) Version() string { return o.release }

func detailsOfMobile(a App) string {
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Here is the details of the *%s* with the version %s", a.Name(), a.Version())
    return message
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(detailsOfMobile(mobile{version: "1", appName: "iDaft"}))
    fmt.Println(detailsOfMobile(other{release: "2", app_name: "Shazam"}))
}

// Here is the details of the *iDaft* with the version 1
// Here is the details of the *Shazam* with the version 2
```

As a simpler approach, you could also just make both structs implement the well known `Stringer` interface:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mobile struct {
    version string
    appName string
}

func (m mobile) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s version %s", m.appName, m.version)
}

type other struct {
    release  string
    app_name string
}

func (o other) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s release %s", o.app_name, o.release)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(mobile{version: "1", appName: "iDaft"})
    fmt.Println(other{release: "2", app_name: "Shazam"})
}

// iDaft version 1
// Shazam release 2
```

Comment: from a language perspective this is correct; but when I read the question, it seems to me OP should not use value reference as type definition. The definition `something with a name and a version` is valid for both `mobile`, `other`, `desktop` etc Those reference names are variables of a more general `type def struct {name, version string }`

Comment: I think you're probably right @mh-cbon, it's hard to know whether the OP's simplified example lost some context as to why these are different structs, but certainly something like `struct {type, name, version string}` is also worth considering.