# Golang - best practice for using same function for two structs with same field

Tags: go, methods, struct

Imagine I have these two structs:

```go
type Game struct {
    Name string
    MultiplayerSupport bool
    Genre string
    Version string
}

type ERP struct {
    Name string
    MRPSupport bool
    SupportedDatabases []string
    Version string
}
```

I want a function attached to these structs that will print the `Version` variable

```go
func (e *ERP) PrintVersion()  {
    fmt.Println("Version is", e.Version)
}
```

I know I can use an interface, but I still have to define two identical functions for both of the structs, which is code repetition.

What is the best practice here to prevent code repetition?

P.S. Before you flag it with "This question already has an aswer here", it is not the same question since on following question, field names between the structs differ.

[Best practice to use the same function with different structs - Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393728/best-practice-to-use-the-same-function-with-different-structs-golang)

Answer (score 4):

While I was preparing the question, it occured to me that I can implement something like this:

```go
type Version string

func (v Version) PrintVersion() {
    fmt.Println("Version is", v)
}
```

Since all custom types (not only structs) can be method receivers.

Then I can use this type on the structs using [composition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/composition-in-golang/):

```go
type Game struct {
    Name               string
    MultiplayerSupport bool
    Genre              string
    Version
}

type ERP struct {
    Name               string
    MRPSupport         bool
    SupportedDatabases []string
    Version
}
```

Then I can use it just like a normal string field (which indeed it is!)

```go
func main() {

    g := Game{
        "Fear Effect",
        false,
        "Action-Adventure",
        "1.0.0",
    }

    g.PrintVersion()
    // Version is 1.0.0


    e := ERP{
        "Logo",
        true,
        []string{"ms-sql"},
        "2.0.0",
    }

    e.PrintVersion()
    // Version is 2.0.0

}
```

Comment: Perfect example of how [method forwarding](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding) works