# Reuse a function in Go across multiple structs

Tags: go

:)
I know this is going to seem like a duplicate question, but every question I've found has not actually answered what I'm trying to do, exactly. I'm new to Go, so I could be missing something small.

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251278/golang-best-practice-for-using-same-function-for-two-structs-with-same-field), but the difference for me is that I need a function that access multiple attributes instead of just a single one. I'm not looking for an interface. I want to have this function code a single time, because it is the same for every different struct.

I'm new to Go, but I think the function needs to accept/use pointers for the structs, because I need them to update.

Example:

```
type ModelA struct {
    choices  []string 
    cursor   int     
    selected string
    name     string   
}

type ModelB struct {
    choices  []string 
    cursor   int     
    selected string   
    year     int
}

func (m ModelA or ModelB) CommonFunction(originalString string, otherArguments ) string {
    originalString += question

    // Iterate over our choices
    for idx, choice := range m.choices {

        // Is the cursor pointing at this choice?
        cursor := " " // no cursor
        if m.cursor == idx {
            cursor = ">" // cursor!
        }

        // Is this choice selected?
        checked := " " // not selected
        if m.selected == choice {
            checked = "x" // selected!
        }

        // Render the row
        originalString += fmt.Sprintf("%s [%s] %s\n", cursor, checked, choice)
    }

    originalString += "\nPress ctrl + q to quit.\n"
    return "\n" + originalString + "\n\n"
}
```

I'm not sure what I want to do is possible, but I'd like to know from someone who is more of a Golang expert than I.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do [struct embedding](https://gobyexample.com/struct-embedding) :)

https://go.dev/play/p/mEsvmtlHbPL

```golang
type inner struct {
    choices  []string
    cursor   int
    selected string
}

type ModelA struct {
    inner
    name string
}

type ModelB struct {
    inner
    year int
}

func (m inner) CommonFunction() string {
    // ...
    return "common"
}

func main() {
    modelAinstance := &ModelA{
        name: "hello",
    }
    modelAinstance.CommonFunction()

    modelBinstance := &ModelB{
        year: 2012,
    }
    modelBinstance.CommonFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code show, I make some changes here:

```golang
type Model struct {
    choices  []string 
    cursor   int     
    selected string
}

type ModelA struct {
    Model
    name     string   
}

type ModelB struct {
    Model
    year     int
}

func (m Model) CommonFunction(originalString string, otherArguments) string {
    // your function body
}

func main() {
    a := ModelA{}
    a.CommonFunction("test A")
    b := ModelB{}
    b.CommonFunction("test B")
}
```

Then you can reuse your function by `inheriting` the `Model`.

You can learn more about `inherit` in `Golang` here: https://golangbot.com/inheritance/. It is about [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).